# Prove that if $a,b\in R \Rightarrow \operatorname{frontier} (a,b)=\{a,b\}$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

This would be the general case because I want to know how to prove that the frontier from(0,1)={0,1}. so, if i know the general case, i will know the particular case.

Def. if A $\subset R \Rightarrow \operatorname{Frontier}(A)=\{x \in R :\forall r>0 (B_r(x)\cap A \neq \varnothing \land B_r(x)\cap A^c \neq \varnothing )\}$

Def. $ B_r(x)=\{y\in R: \|x-y\|<r\}$

Comment: What does your notation $Br(x)$ mean?

Comment: I have already add the definition from $ B_r(x) $

Comment: Then I think your definition of Frontier is missing $\forall r>0$.

Comment: yeah yeah, your right. let me add that

Comment: You just need to show that $\forall r>0$, $Br(a)$ intersects $(a, b)$, and its complement.  Then show the same for $Br(b)$. Then you have to show that for any other real number, that doesn’t hold.

Comment: Also, just a super technical point, I’m assuming that $a<b$, but if that’s not assumed, and for example $a=b$, then $(a,b)=(a,a)=\emptyset$, so the frontier is NOT $\{a\}$.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can convince yourself of the following alternative way of looking at things; which works well whenever you understand what convergence is.

$x$ is in $\text{Frontier}(S)$ of some set $S$ inside a topological space $\mathbb X$ iff:

$$\begin{array}{rl} 1.& \text{There is a sequence $x_n$ in $S$ with $(x_n) \to x$},\\
 2.& \text{There is a sequence $y_n$ in $\mathbb X\,\backslash\, S$ with $(y_n) \to x$.}
\end{array}$$

So in this setting, you can try the constant sequence $(b)$ to verify 1. and $(b + 1/n)_{n \ge 1}$ for 2.

(In a general topological space, $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if and only if for even open set $U$ containing $x$, $(x_n)$ is eventually inside $U$.)